# Running sum in background

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

Modified Question.

My fitness app will calculate the number of calories burned based on a calculated value for each second.  I have a timer that will allow the app to pick back up should it.  I can't get the running sum to continue calculating when the app goes into the background.  I tried to place the running sum inside of a DispatchQueue but not getting the sum as expected.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I have placed inside the function that updates the timer.

```
//MARK: - Update Timer Label
func updateTimerLabel() {

    interval = -Int(timerStartDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)

    time = interval

    let hours = interval / 3600
    let minutes = interval / 60 % 60
    let seconds = interval % 60

    print("Current interval = \(interval)")

    timerLabel.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        if self.activityArray[self.currentArrayRow].2 <= 4.5 {

            self.cps = self.activityArray[self.currentArrayRow].2 * Double(self.user.userWeightInKilo) / 3600

            self.runningCPS = self.runningCPS + self.cps

            print("MET \(self.activityArray[self.currentArrayRow].2) <= 4.5 * KG (\(Double(self.user.userWeightInKilo))) * HR (\(Double(self.user.userHeartRate))) / MaxHR (\(Double(self.user.maxHeartRate))  * interval \(Double(self.interval)) / 3600. Gives a cps 0f \(self.cps) and a runningCPS of \(self.runningCPS) ")

    } else {

            self.cps = self.activityArray[self.currentArrayRow].2 * Double(self.user.userWeightInKilo) * Double(self.user.userHeartRate) / Double(self.user.maxHeartRate) / 3600

            self.runningCPS = self.runningCPS + self.cps

            print("MET \(self.activityArray[self.currentArrayRow].2) > 4.5 * KG (\(Double(self.user.userWeightInKilo))) * HR (\(Double(self.user.userHeartRate))) / MaxHR (\(Double(self.user.maxHeartRate))  * interval \(Double(self.interval)) / 3600. Gives a cps 0f \(self.cps) and a runningCPS of \(self.runningCPS) ")


    }

}

    activeLabel.text = String(format: "%0.1f", runningCPS) + " Calories Burned"

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.raywenderlich.com/113835-ios-timer-tutorial

Comment: I have asked a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031931/ios-check-if-user-has-notification-to-be-scheduled .

Comment: From iOS 13 you can use BGTaskScheduler - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks